# Convergence Rate of Stochastic Gradient Method analysis with more realistic stochastic graident bound

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, machine-learning, gradient-descent, subgradient

I am reading this [Lectur Slides](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Eschmidtm/Courses/540-W19/L11.pdf) of SGD convergence analysis. In page 3, it says the realistic bound "Just get some extra terms in the result."

I tried to use this bound and derive the result, but didn't succeed. What is the result with this [realistic bound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GaWy.png)? What are those extra terms?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.